# Как сдублировать строку в таблице и вернуть id новой строки? ORA-00933

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert, дублирование

Задача: сдублировать строку в таблице и вернуть `id` новой строки. Т.к. таблица имеет очень много столбцов, хотелось бы это сделать без лишних телодвижений.

Вот что я попытался сделать, но это не работает:

```
DECLARE
  new_id NUMBER;
  old_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
old_id:=2584;
INSERT INTO table_name_44 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
  SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
    FROM table_name_44
   WHERE old_id:=2584
RETURNING column_id INTO new_id;
END;
```

> Error report -
> ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
> PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Как вернуть `id` после конструкции `INSERT .... SELECT`? Может другие способы есть?

Можно на PL/SQL или SQL.

Comment: Дополнил ответ пояснением, почему так не работает, если вам это интересно.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так не получится. `RETURNING` не поддерживается во вставке `INSERT...SELECT`.
Посмотрите синтаксическую диаграмму [single_table_insert::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423), в ветке с подзапросом *returning_clause* отсутствует.

Сделайте так:

```
create table tab (
    id int generated by default on null as identity, col1 int, col2 int)
/
insert into tab values (null, 123, 456);

declare
    row tab%rowtype;
    newid int;
    oldid int := 1;
begin
    select * into row
    from tab
    where id = oldid;

    row.id := null;
    insert into tab values row
    returning id into newid;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
select * from tab;

        ID       COL1       COL2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        123        456
         2        123        456
```